# Why GCP Dataflow jobs in Asia region takes more time to start-process-stop than Europe region

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I was working with multiple dataflow jobs. Requirement was to run the dataflow batch jobs for an application in Europe region (europe-west1). Those Europe region dataflow job took around 7-10 mins to complete the whole process (Starting-processing-stopping).
Now the same requirement is asked by Asia region. So I changes all the relevant pipeline parameter and other GCP component's region to Asia (asia-southeast1). But this time the dataflow job took more time to start, more time process and more time to stop the workers. For example, **for the same dataset**, which **took 7 to 10 mins there to complete earlier in Europe region**; it is **now taking 20-30 mins to complete in Asia region**.

I compared all the settings, config and necessary logs. All components are in Asia region. But could not find any reason for this delay in Asia region.

Is there any known issue with Asia Dataflow workers in GCP? Or I am missing something here. Please guide me to identify the issue.

Comment: Anyone has any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

The time to start up/shut down workers in a region can vary depending on how crowded the region is. The other question to ask is where you data is, which will take longer to read and write when remote (including your specified temp directory and, for starting up, staging directory).

Comment: So startup and shutdown is taking more time as you said along with the data processing. I suspected this as a regional network issue.